# Non Homogeneous into Homogeneous differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, homogeneous-equation

How can I turn this differential equation into a homogeneous differential equation $$y' = 2x + \frac{8y}{x} + 1$$?

Comment: What are you trying to do since your question does not presently make sense? It can be solved using an Integrating Factor.

Comment: You might mean the associated homogeneous linear differential equation, $y^\prime-\frac{8}{x}y=0$.  If you find a particular solution to the inhomogeneous linear differential equation, the family of solutions can be found is the sum of the family of solutions to the associated homogeneous equation and the particular solution.

Comment: I can solve it by finding the Integrating factor. I want to solve it by turning it into a Homogeneous differential equation. I think along the lines of what qman is saying.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are after the solution to the above, here is how I would tackle it:
$$
y'-\frac{8}{x}y=2x+1
$$
And mulitplying both sides by $\exp(-8\int\frac{1}{x}dx)=\frac{1}{x^8}$, we get an exact equation
$$
\frac{1}{x^8}y'-\frac{1}{x^9}y=\frac{2x+1}{x^8}\Rightarrow(\frac{1}{x^8}y)'=\frac{2x+1}{x^8}\Rightarrow \frac{y}{x^8}=\int\frac{2x+1}{x^8}\\
\Rightarrow \frac{y}{x^8}=\frac{-1}{4x^8}-\frac{1}{x^9}+c\Rightarrow y=cx^8-\frac{1}{4}-1/x
$$

Comment: I think you mean $y = c x^{8} - 1/4 - 1/x$

Comment: Thank you qbert but I am trying to solve it by turning the equation in to a Homogeneous differential equation.

Comment: @Mattos I do, thank you